# moving from Fedora 12 to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04

I recently moved from using Fedora to Ubuntu.

The reason I was using Fedora in the first place was that I was using Redhat at work. Now I am trying out Ubuntu and will finally settle for one (update to Fedora13 or use Ubuntu) in a couple of days.

[image]

What should I expect different here? What is awesome and what is missing?

Comment: "Ubuntu" sounds more euphonious and exotic than "Fedora". Chicks dig that when you are chatting them up and talk about your distro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a presentation on the differences between the Red Hat Way and the Debian Way at Ohio LinuxFest last year.  It includes things like package management and location of configuration files.  Slides are here:  http://www.slideshare.net/macoafi/sysadmins-rosetta-stone

Answer (score 1):

The package repository is huge and community support is excellent for ubuntu. Other than that I like the package management and its desktop friendly approach. I haven't used fedora that much to tell the difference other than the fact that apache2 is named httpd in red hat machines:).  The most awesome thing about ubuntu for me the options of diferent repository for a lot of applications. Here are 2 articles on difference between fedora 13 and ubuntu 10.04

[One](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/features/ubuntu-10-04-vs-fedora-13/)

[Two](http://www.hackourlives.com/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-vs-fedora-13-goddard/)